# SELECT SUM for time

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a Table in SQL server with a column "Time" having data type as time(7). Need to call the sum of this column, and when I use the following statement, it returns result as integer only.
Eg. If total time is 1:30:00,I expect result as 1.5. But the code I use doesn't get me this, it get me result as 1. Please check if you have a solution.

The code I used is

```
SELECT SUM(DATEPART(ss,Time) + DATEPART(mi,Time)*60 + DATEPART(hh,Time)*3600)/3600 AS TotalTime FROM dbo.Table
```

Comment: Integer division?

Comment: Also check what the different parts of the calculation give you, e.g. `DATEPART(ss,Time)` or `DATEPART(hh,Time)*3600` just to be sure you're good there.

Comment: The result I get is DATEPART(hh,Time)*3600)/3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divide some value by `int` type, the result will be also `int` (the fraction is just dropped). Therefore, you need to convert a divider of 3600 from `int` to `decimal`:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEPART(ss,Time) + DATEPART(mi,Time)*60 + DATEPART(hh,Time)*3600)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,4), 3600) AS TotalTime FROM dbo.Table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (
    DATEPART(hh,Time) +
    DATEPART(mi,Time) / 60.0 +
    DATEPART(ss,Time) / 3600.0
) AS TotalTime
FROM dbo.Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below - you don't need sum() function here and in your case, it is showing 1 because your result is 5400/3600 which is 1 but you need to add a float value as you are expecting float result

```
 SELECT (DATEPART(ss,'1:30:00') + DATEPART(mi,'1:30:00')*60 + 
 DATEPART(hh,'1:30:00')*3600)/3600.00
 AS TotalTime FROM dbo.Table
```

Comment: This works good, but I need SUM() as I want sum of the column

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can change the datepart argument based on your needs [here is the full list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', [Time]) as float)/60) AS TotalHours FROM [dbo].[Table]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference in decimal hours, then do the following:

- Convert the time values to seconds.
- Sum the seconds.
- Divide by 60 * 60

So:

```
select sum(datediff(second, 0, v.t)) / (60.0 * 60)
from (values (convert(time, '00:10:01')), 
             (convert(time, '01:00:03'))
     ) v(t)
```

There is no reason to break the value in to component parts.  That just seems unnecessarily complicated.